# Cassandra Services not getting started

Tags: cassandra, datastax

Hi facing this problem with apache cassandra , upon installation
everything works fine but randomly after a day or two the following
services stops and i am not able to start them back again. When trying
to restart it says "Windows service started and stopped automatically". I
think it has something to do with prunsrv.exe and prunsrv_old.exe

DataStax Cassandra Community Server
DataStax OpsCenter Agent

I am running cassandra 2.2.7

Note: When i uninstall and install it back again it the services are started and it works fine for some time.

Answer (score 0):

1.Please check your log at location `C:\Program Files\DataStax-DDC\logs` you may have some corrupted file which need to be deleted.

2.Corrupted file at location `C:\Program Files\DataStax-DDC\data\data\..\{filename}`(Verify in log)

3.Restart your service

4.Open your connection